# C++ скачивание строки

Tags: c++, сеть

Я хочу сделать свое приложения более нативным, чистое - без использования сторонних библиотек. Появилась задача скачать строку. Я знаю всем известный способ сделать это, используя `CURL`, но чтобы использовать `CURL` необходимо подключать `-lcurl`.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то скачать строку иным методом?

**P.S.**  скачать строку - получить страницу из интернета в string.

Comment: Можно. WinInet, WinSock

Comment: Осталось выяснить, **как** (каким протоколом) скачивать и реализовать его. И определиться - считать ли те же сокеты сторонними библиотеками  или нет...